# What is the meaning of Opionated?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm currently reading a [tutorial](https://www.graph.cool/docs/quickstart/) of graphQL from graphcool, and came across the word "opionated".

> The Graphcool Framework is a self-hosted BaaS to develop serverless
>   GraphQL backends. It offers an **opionated** [sic] backend setup, including
>   GraphQL database mapping, subscriptions and permission system. Simply
>   install Graphcool’s command line tool to get started:

I then searched from Google "define" as well as various dictionary, but found no meaning for opionated. I did find some pages that do use that word (like [this](https://anchor.fm/opionatedanswer)), but still can't conclude the exact meaning of opionated. I'm torn between "simplified", "shortcut", and "pampered" (like, a very dumbed down version to make it very simple for even a newbie, like "opium" cmp. "opion"). But other websites (like [this](https://anchor.fm/opionatedanswer)) use "opionated" in different way, which can mean "exchange" or "little by little". Can somebody help explain?

Comment: This is a misspelling of "opinionated", used in a specific technical way that is not necessarily relevant to English as a whole. You may do better to ask what "opinionated" means for frameworks on e.g. [SoftwareEngineering.SE], or on their chat.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks. I don't know that it was misspelt. I felt I have ever seen that word once somewhere in the past, so I thought it was an existing word.

Comment: This question appears to have been caused by a typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one is unlikely to help future readers, so I'm voting to close it as off-topic for ELL.

Comment: I'm the author of the mentioned tutorial and I can confirm that this is literally just a typo. I'm really sorry for causing this confusion! :facepalm:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a misspelling.  The most common word that it could be is "opinionated" which means "holding strong opinions"

> I was difficult to have a chat with John, because he was so opinionated. Every time I talked to him it became an argument.

It is often used in a rather negative way, and this meaning doesn't seem to apply to a "backend setup".

Alternatively, it could be a misspelling for "optionated" This is not a standard word, but can be formed from "option" + "-ate" + "-ed" in a regular way.  It would mean "having many options" (but this word is not found in an dictionary that I have checked).  It would mean that the *backend setup has many options*.

My guess, from the context, would be that the second meaning was intended. But as it is a mistake, only the author could be certain what they meant.

Comment: After searching through, I think "opinionated" is correct, because there are also instance of "unopinionated". https://stackoverflow.com/a/802093/3003927 Thanks for actually answering!